# Как сделать бесшовный фон, в котором элементы зеркальны?

Tags: css

В стандартном бесшовном фоне элементы просто повторяются, для этого достаточно просто написать в css:

```
body{
background: url(Картинка.png);
}
```

Но как сделать, чтобы после обычной картинки, шла её зеркальная копия?
Например так:[image: Пример]

Даже если будет 2 картинки, то как их чередовать так, как на примере?

Comment: что мешает просто сделать такой фон одной картинкой?

Comment: @teran, Одной картинкой? Она же маленькая будет, а надо чтобы она была "зациклена" на весь фон

Comment: Можно использовать картинку из двух стрелок, указывающих друг на друга.

Comment: @VTT, точно.  Спасибо:)

Comment: @VTT, но всё же интересно, можно ли сделать так? Чтобы на одной картинке одна стрелка была?

Comment: Это регулируется свойством `background-repeat`, но там такого режима не предусмотрено.